# How to provide multiple values in THEN for a where clause in SQL

Tags: sql

I'm trying to write a SQL query like the one below

```
select [ProductId], [Product]
from Products p
where p.ProductType = case 
                  when @condition1 then 'p'
                  when @condition2 then 'p','c'
                  else p.ProductType 
                end
```

How can I achieve this?

1. when @condition1 is true, I want to get products where productType = 'p'
2. when @condition2 is true, I want to get products where productType in ('p','c')
3. when both conditions are false, then get all products

Comment: It's generally better to use AND/OR constructions instead of case expressions in the WHERE clause.

Comment: What do you want to do If @conditionn2?

Comment: Who is upvoting this question??

Comment: The logic of this condition in the WHERE clause, will always return TRUE for all the rows because of that `else p.ProductType`. Explain what you want.

Comment: not if p.ProductType is null...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic can be expressed without the use of `case`:

```
select [ProductId], [Product]
from Products p
where (@conditionn1 and p.ProductType = 'p') or
      (@conditionn2 and p.ProductType in ('p', 'c')) or
      ( (not @conditionn1) and (not @conditionn2) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome!

Not sure if I understand your question, but this is how I would re-write:

```
SELECT 
    ProductId, 
    Product,
    CASE
        WHEN p.ProductType = "CONDITION1" THEN 'p'
        WHEN p.ProductType = "CONDITION2" THEN 'c'
        ELSE 'ERROR'
    END
FROM
    Products p
```

Comment: I was thinking about this solution. Kinda like to upvote it twice. But it is sad that I can't do so.

Answer (score 0):

you can't pass-in multiple values like so since `p.ProductType` can be set with scalar value; rather you will have to repeat the same condition like

```
where p.ProductType = case 
                  when @conditionn1 then 'p'
                  when @conditionn2 then 'p'
                  when @conditionn2 then 'c'
                  else p.ProductType 
                end
```

Comment: But the 'c' will never be reached.